# Layout NLog properties as JSON?

Tags: logging, serialization, nlog

I am trying to figure out how to log all the properties in a `LogEventInfo` object to a JSON-formatted string.  Per the [issue on github](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/723), I tried to do something like this:

```xml
<target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="coloredConsole">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
    <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
    <attribute name="exception" layout="${onexception:${exception:format=tostring}}" />
    <attribute name="properties" encode="false">
      <layout type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="properties" layout="${all-event-properties}" />
      </layout>
    </attribute>
  </layout>
</target>
```

... but unfortunately, my properties contain complex objects (I have two properties with the names of "properties" and "tags", where "properties" is a `IDictionary<string, object>` and "tags" is an `IList<string>` in the `LogEventInfo.Properties` property) that simply do not serialize.  I end up with something resembling this:

```json
{ "timestamp": "2017-05-18 08:41:28.7730", "level": "INFO", "properties": { "properties": "properties=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object], tags=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" } }
```

I was expecting (and hoping for) a serialized JSON dictionary that would give me the context of the log message, but clearly that is not what I am getting.

How can I properly serialize the properties in my `LogEventInfo` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it looks like there's a bug in NLog, so I kinda made my own renderer.  Here's what I did.  First, I made an extension method using JSON.NET:

```cs
public static string ToJson(this object obj, bool format = false, string dateFormat = null)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateFormat))
    {
        settings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
        {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter {DateTimeFormat = dateFormat}
        };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, format ? Formatting.Indented : Formatting.None, settings);
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, format ? Formatting.Indented : Formatting.None, settings);
}
```

...next, I created a LayoutRenderer like so:

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("json-event-properties")]
public class JsonEventPropertiesLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Renders the specified environmental information and appends it to the specified <see cref="T:System.Text.StringBuilder" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The <see cref="T:System.Text.StringBuilder" /> to append the rendered data to.</param>
    /// <param name="logEvent">Logging event.</param>
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent) {
        if (logEvent.Properties == null || logEvent.Properties.Count == 0)
            return;
        var serialized = logEvent.Properties.ToJson();
        builder.Append(serialized);
    }
}
```

In my application, when starting up, I registered my `LayoutRenderer` like so:

```cs
LayoutRenderer.Register<JsonEventPropertiesLayoutRenderer>("json-event-properties");
```

... and finally, I configured the NLog target like this:

```xml
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
    <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
    <attribute name="exception" layout="${onexception:${exception:format=tostring}}" />
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    <attribute name="properties" layout="${json-event-properties}" encode="false"/>
  </layout>
```

Running like this, the JSON properly formatted and I got access to the properties in my `LogEventInfo` object.

Comment: When I followed this I am getting the output as {
   "correlation_id":"a03734dd-b0ca-4bcf-83f2-e9d814272e32",   
   "env","dev",
   "properties":"{"Key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}"
}, but my requirement is  {
   "correlation_id":"a03734dd-b0ca-4bcf-83f2-e9d814272e32",  ,
   "env","dev",
   "Key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "keyn":"valuen"
}
where KEY1-VALUE1,KEY2-VALUE2 and the rest of the part is DYNAMIC Can any one help me on this

Comment: @Gowtham.K.Reddy I think this has to do with your JSON serializer.  I use JSON.NET, but I think the standard .NET DataContractJsonSerializer gives you the results you're describing.

Comment: also, dynamic is the devil.  To be avoided at every opportunity `</soapbox>`

Answer (score 9):

Using NLog 4.5.1 here.

With this config:

```xml
 <target xsi:type="File" name="jsonFile2" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-json-nested-${shortdate}.log">
     <layout type="JsonLayout">
         <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
         <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
         <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
         <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false" >
             <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="20"/>
         </attribute>
     </layout>
 </target>
```

this code:

```cs
var nestedData = new
{
    A = "a value",
    B = "b value",
    Nested = new
    {
        A = "nested a value",
        B = "nested b value",
    },
    Ints = new Collection<int> { 1, 2, 3},
    Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"nested", new { X= 'x', y = 'y' }},
        { "awesome", "nlog"}
    }
};
LogEventInfo eventInfo = new LogEventInfo
{
    Level = LogLevel.Info,
    Properties = { {"nestedData", nestedData } }
};
logger.Log(eventInfo);
```

outputs:

```json
{  
   "time":"2018-04-05 18:08:01.0813",
   "level":"INFO",
   "eventProperties":{  
      "nestedData":{  
         "A":"a value",
         "B":"b value",
         "Nested":{  
            "A":"nested a value",
            "B":"nested b value"
         },
         "Ints":[  
            1,
            2,
            3
         ],
         "Dictionary":{  
            "nested":{  
               "X":"x",
               "y":"y"
            },
            "awesome":"nlog"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Actually, it prints the ugly one-line version of this.

See Nested JSON with structured logging [on the NLog wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout)

Pay attention to the `maxRecursionLimit` setting. By default it's 0, meaning "No object reflection", meaning you'll get the `ToString()` representation of your event properties.