# How to make NLog's JsonLayout output object types?

Tags: c#, json, logging, nlog

I'm logging my application's data using NLog, with the JsonLayout layout.  The output I'm getting for my objects doesn't include the type, and I'd like it to log the types with the rest of the JSON.  The collection I'm logging has items of various types, and I'd like the log to specifically state what those are, without the reader having to infer which type it is based on its properties.

Here's what I'm getting

```
"things": [
    [
        {
            "PropertyA": 1,
            "PropertyB": 2,
        }
    ],
    [],
    []
]
```

What I'd like to log is something like JSON.Net's output:

```
"things": [
    [
        {
            "$type": "MyNamespace.MyObject, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890123456",
            "PropertyA": 1,
            "PropertyB": 2,
        }
    ],
    [],
    []
]
```

How do I achieve this?  I'm not set on using JsonLayout if there's something else that'd do equally well.

Comment: This isn't implemented. I would recommend for now to copy the JsonLayout and add it to the code: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Layouts/JsonLayout.cs. Check also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component

Comment: What if you created your own LogJson extension method(s) which serialized your object to JSON using Json.Net with your desired settings and then passed the string through to NLog?

Comment: An example of a `LayoutRenderer` that uses Json.NET can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072023/3744182) to [Layout NLog properties as JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44048187/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

NLog automatically injects a Type-property for Exception-objects. But you can override the NLog IJsonConverter so it happens for all objects:

You can override the JSON conversion like this:

```
internal class JsonLogTypeSerializer : NLog.IJsonConverter
{
    private NLog.IJsonConverter _originalConverter;
    public JsonLogModelSerializer(NLog.IJsonConverter originalConverter)
    {
        _originalConverter = originalConverter;
    }

    /// <summary>Serialization of an object into JSON format.</summary>
    /// <param name="value">The object to serialize to JSON.</param>
    /// <param name="builder">Output destination.</param>
    /// <returns>Serialize succeeded (true/false)</returns>
    public bool SerializeObject(object value, System.Text.StringBuilder builder)
    {
        if ( Convert.GetTypeCode(value) == TypeCode.Object
          && !(value is Exception)
          && !(value is IFormattable)
          && !(value is IEnumerable)
          && !value.GetType().IsValueType)
        {
            builder.Append("\"Type\": \"").Append(value.GetType().ToString()).Append("\" ");
        }

        return _originalConverter.SerializeObject(value, builder);
    }
}
```

Then you can activate the special JsonConverter:

```
var oldJsonConverter = NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter;
var newConverter = new JsonLogTypeSerializer(oldJsonConverter);
NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter = newConverter;
```